# How to resolve issues with accessing paths containing @ in directory name

Tags: perl, path

```
WA=/perl/temp@23 (ENV PARAM)

    if (defined $ENV{'WA'}) {
        $ENV{'AC'} = "$ENV{'WA'}/right";
    }
    eval(qq|use lib "$ENV{'AC'}/lib"|);
```

Error-- Possible unintended interpolation of @23 in string at (eval 1) line 1.

I tried the below solutions and none of them were of great help.

Attempt 1: Didn't work

```
$ENV{'WA'} =~ s/(^.*)@(.*)/$1\@$2/;
if (defined $ENV{'WA'}) {
    $ENV{'AC'} = "$ENV{'WA'}/right";
}
eval(qq|use lib "$ENV{'AC'}/lib"|);
```

I saw one more issue with this.
When it worked once..no clue why and how it worked,but  the lib was not added to @INC path.

Attempt 2: Didn't work - i saw in a post that \x40 represents @

```
$ENV{'WA'} =~ s/(^.*)@(.*)/$1\x40$2/;
if (defined $ENV{'WA'}) {
    $ENV{'AC'} = "$ENV{'WA'}/right";
}
eval(qq|use lib "$ENV{'AC'}/lib"|);
```

Attempt 3: one error to the next

```
$ENV{'WA'} =~ s/(^.*)(@)(.*)/$1\@$3/;
if (defined $ENV{'WA'}) {
    $ENV{'AC'} = "$ENV{'WA'}/right";
}
my $str = $ENV{'AC'};
eval(qq|use lib "$str/lib"|);
use module
```

Error: Can't locate module in @INC
Atleast now i don't get unintended interpolation @

Can someone give me some pointers on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Attempt 1 would work if you escaped it fully `s/@/\\@/g`

Comment: Thanks Chris, with the change you mentioned i encounter the issue i mentioned with Attempt 3. Can't locate the module in@INC. eval statement is supposed to include the path in the @INC for the module

Comment: it'd probably be worth printing out what you're trying to add and/or the contents of `@INC` just to make sure you're added the right path

Comment: `use` is a compile-time statement. Your `use module` statement will be evaluated before your `eval(qq|use lib ...|)` statement, so your `use lib ...` isn't doing any good anyway.

Comment: removing eval seemed to work , but now i am back to square one. Can't locate module in @INC. strangely the paths i print...seems to take the workarea  as temp and not temp@23 which actually has the module

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the question is marked as -1, as it is not clear to me.
I would like to understand and correct myself. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the string eval?

```
BEGIN {
    if (defined $ENV{WA}) {
        $ENV{AC} = "$ENV{WA}/right";
    }
}

use lib "$ENV{AC}/lib";
```

Or, if you only want to set the @INC if AC is defined:

```
use if defined $ENV{AC},
    lib => do { no warnings 'uninitialized'; "$ENV{AC}/lib" };
```

Comment: @ikegami: The warning happens, because the argument is evaluated even if the `if` condition is false.

Comment: @ikegami: no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
use lib
     defined($ENV{WA}) ? "$ENV{WA}/right/lib"
   : defined($ENV{AC}) ? "$ENV{AC}/lib"
   : ();
```

or

```
use lib
   defined($ENV{WA}) ? "$ENV{WA}/right/lib" : (),
   defined($ENV{AC}) ? "$ENV{AC}/lib"       : ();
```